# Azure DevOps deploy Angular app to IIS with Octopus

Tags: azure-devops, devops, octopus-deploy, azure-devops-pipelines, octopus

I'm trying to deploy a `Angular` application to my `IIS` server using `Octopus` and `Azure DevOps`

My application has multiple environments, each environment with it's own settings (`config.prod.json`)

**What I want to do**

Basically Octopus should take the release from Azure DevOps, and copy the release to multiple folders, with different `config.prod.json` files.
Each folder corresponds to a specific IIS website.

**Azure DevOps pipeline setup**

1. Use Node 14.x
2. npm install
3. ng build --prod
4. Archive dis/angular-app ;  Archive type: zip
5. Publish Artifact; Path `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Triggers : Enable continuous integration

**Azure DevOps Releases setup**

**1. Package Application for Octopus**

[image]

**2. Push Package(s) to Octopus**

[image]

**3. Create Octopus Release**

[image]

**Octopus setup**

One step `DEPLOY TO IIS`

**1. Package details**

[image]

**2. Custom Installation Directory**

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

**3. IIS Web Site and Application Pool**
[image]
[image]

**Errors**
In IIS while I click `Binding`, `Basic settings`, I get this error: `There was an error while performing this operation. The parameter  is incorrect`

Also, the folder mapped in iis for the website that I'm targeting. Contains a folder `drop` with the zip file `27.zip` (27 is the release id)

1. How do I unzip the zip file?
2. How do I replicate the zip file to the other environments?
3. Is my configuration ok so far? What am I doing wrong?

Just a few of the links that I've checked:

https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploy-aspnetcore-app/to-iis/using-octopus-onprem-azure-devops-builtin
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFqrWsUPCAM&t=345s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeNYtYuhZQ4&t=2s

Comment: 1. You can unzip the files using the ExtracFiles tasks.
2. Copy the files multiple times?